# Java criticial section seems not work

Tags: java, android, concurrency

Here is the code:

```
final CountDownLatch lineDirectionLatch = new CountDownLatch(count);
final Object lock = new Object();
for(StationLines station : stationList) {
    final String gpsNumber = station.getGpsNumber();
    for(String lineNumber : station.getLines()) {
        final TranslateToStationTask task = new TranslateToStationTask(lineNumber, gpsNumber);
        task.setCallback(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    Utils.debug(TAG, "Thead " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " enter critical section.");
                    int errorCode = task.getTaskResult().getErrorCode();
                    if (errorCode == 0) {
                        Station station = task.getTaskResult().getContent();
                        if (station != null) {
                        for(int idx = 0; idx < stationList.size(); idx++) {
                            String gpsNumber = stationList.get(idx).getGpsNumber();
                            if (gpsNumber.equals(station.getGpsNumber())) {
                                    stationList.get(idx).setDirection(station.getLineNumber(), station.getDirection());
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    } 
                    Utils.debug(TAG, "Thead " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " leave critical section.");
                    lineDirectionLatch.countDown();
                }
            }});
        task.startTask();
    }
}
lineDirectionLatch.await();
```

Herer is the log:

```
03-26 19:57:07.648: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1501 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.687: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1501 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.714: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1502 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.722: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1502 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.726: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1503 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.726: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1503 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.769: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1509 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.773: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1505 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.773: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1505 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.804: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1506 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.804: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1506 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.804: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1507 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.804: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1507 leave critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.804: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1510 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.843: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1511 enter critical section.
03-26 19:57:07.843: I/TrafficManager(20013): Thead 1513 enter critical section.
```

You can see Thread 1505 enters the critical section beore the previous entered thread(1509), and thread 1509 never leaves the critical section ? It's odd.

Every TranslateToStationTask runs in it's own thread, and the critical section will be called, when the task finished it's work.

I have no idea why the critical section allows mutiple task enters, and why some tasks seem never leave the critical section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a try-catch clause inside the synchronized block to look if the function leaves abnormally and therefore unlock the object without notice.

Something like that:

```
synchronized(lock) {
  try {
    // my code
  }
  catch (Exception e) { // generic catch to look if any exception is triggered
    System.out.printf("Caused exception: %s",e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Another possible problem is that you create an anonymous class with new Runnable() so it may be possible that lock is not always the same variable. Try to create a class implementing Runnable together with the lock variable and call that constructor.

Comment: Yes, there is an exception, and the lock is released without notice, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

From your code it looks like you are creating the `lock` object in the function itself.
So each time the function is called, there will be a new lock for different threads.

Hence they all will enter your critical section.

To get the desired behaviour move it out of this function.

Comment: Yes, but the log is from one call for the function.

Comment: @user1184113 Define your lock `static` and see what happens.

Comment: static modifier is not allowed.

Comment: I have tried to define the lock object to be an instance variable, but the result is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Thread 1509 is not leaving the critical section anywhere in the log. Perhaps it waits on `lock`, what would allow other threads to enter the critical section? (Unlikely, as `lock` does not seem to be passed anywhere out of the method in the code fragment).

Comment: No, the TranslateToStationTask is not wait on any lock.